# Cannot return desired header info through Fetch or Axios

Tags: ajax, react-native, fetch, axios

I recently need to call an API to login my account in react native. I had tried to use fetch and Axios library to perform AJAX call to the server. Unfortunately, it didn't return the header i want. But, I try to use https://apitester.com/ to test the API, it perform well. Can anyone tell me my mistake?

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solution. It needs to add mode:'no-cors'.